# How to update preceding record with data from following row within same group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a set of data where I need to update preceding record date column (earlier date) with date from a different column in following row (older date -if exists) within the same group.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 so I can't use LEAD/LAG functions.

Data before update:

```
ArticleId | DiscountStartDate   | DiscountEndDate     | Price
-------------------------------------
1         | 2018-08-10 23:59:59 | null                | 20    
1         | 2018-08-20 10:00:00 | null                | 30    
1         | 2019-01-10 01:00:00 | null                | 20
2         | 2018-11-10 12:00:00 | null                | 10    
1         | 2019-01-15 11:30:00 | null                | 21    
3         | 2018-05-10 12:00:00 | 2019-01-14 14:00:00 | 20    
3         | 2018-07-10 23:00:00 | 2019-01-14 14:00:00 | 10    
3         | 2019-01-10 12:00:00 | 2019-01-14 14:00:00 | 5    
4         | 2018-12-20 00:00:00 | 2019-01-19 14:00:00 | 20


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ArticleDiscount](
[ArticleID] [int] NULL,
[DiscountStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
[DiscountEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Price] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ArticleDiscount]
       ([ArticleID]
       ,[DiscountStartDate]
       ,[DiscountEndDate]
       ,[Price])
 VALUES
(1, '2018-08-10 23:59:59', null, 20),
(1, '2018-08-20 10:00:00', null, 30),
(1, '2019-01-10 01:00:00', null, 20),
(2, '2018-11-10 12:00:00', null, 10),
(1, '2019-01-15 11:30:00', null, 21),
(3, '2018-05-10 12:00:00', '2019-01-14 14:00:00' , 20),
(3, '2018-07-10 23:00:00', '2019-01-14 14:00:00' , 10),
(3, '2019-01-10 12:00:00', '2019-01-14 14:00:00' , 5),
(4, '2018-12-20 00:00:00', '2019-01-19 14:00:00' , 20)
```

Data after update:

```
ArticleId | DiscountStartDate   | DiscountEndDate     | Price
-------------------------------------
1         | 2018-08-10 23:59:59 | 2018-08-20 10:00:00 | 20    
1         | 2018-08-20 10:00:00 | 2019-01-10 01:00:00 | 30    
1         | 2019-01-10 01:00:00 | 2019-01-15 11:30:00 | 20    
2         | 2018-11-10 12:00:00 | null                | 10    
1         | 2019-01-15 11:30:00 | null                | 21    
3         | 2018-05-10 12:00:00 | 2018-07-10 23:00:00 | 20    
3         | 2018-07-10 23:00:00 | 2019-01-10 12:00:00 | 10    
3         | 2019-01-10 12:00:00 | 2019-01-14 14:00:00 | 5    
4         | 2018-12-20 00:00:00 | 2019-01-19 14:00:00 | 20
```

edit: Basically if there is newer entry (DiscountStartDate) for specific ArticleId I need to close the DiscountEndDate in preceding record for that ArticleID. DiscountEndDate in the newest record should stay untouched (AtricleId 2,4 because there are no other records for them and newest records for ArticleId 1 and 3) and it does not matter if there is null or some date in records.

Comment: What is the logic to calculate `DiscountEndDate'?

Comment: Moreover, show your attempt code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the date based on articleid you can try like following.

```
UPDATE t 
SET    DiscountEndDate = case when d.ddate is null then DiscountEndDate else d.ddate end
FROM   [ArticleDiscount] t 
       CROSS apply (SELECT Min(discountstartdate) ddate 
                    FROM   [ArticleDiscount] t1 
                    WHERE  t1.articleid = t.articleid 
                           AND t1.discountstartdate > t.discountstartdate)d
```

[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/OCK12029)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately last two rows for articleid 3 and 4 have null after update.

Comment: are you not updating the values based on ArticleId, for last two rows it will be null as second last record with article id don't have any further article with id 3 and same is the case with 4

Comment: Last record for ArticleId=3 with DiscountStartDate=2019-01-10 12:00:00 is the newest one and it has DiscountEndDate - this date should not be updated. ArticleId=4 and ArticleId=2 - there is just one record for them and they should not be updated (stay the same) aswell

Comment: I have updated the anser please check it should work now

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same using `OUTER APPLY` and `TOP` as below

```
UPDATE t SET t.DiscountEndDate = t1.DiscountStartDate
FROM #ArticleDiscount t
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 DiscountStartDate
            FROM #ArticleDiscount t1
            WHERE t1.ArticleID = t.ArticleID 
            AND t1.DiscountStartDate > t.DiscountStartDate) t1
WHERE t1.DiscountStartDate IS NOT NULL
```